# Calculate total number of likes on specific date in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am using Graph API for getting insights of the page. For that i am using link like
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/PageID/insights/page_fans/lifetime?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&since=2014-07-01&until=2014-07-15
I am getting total no. of like until date. 
I want to show the total no. of users liked page in specific date like 2014-07-01,2014-07-02,2014-07-03....
Thanks for help..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `page_fan_adds` metric:

```
GET /{page_id}/insights/page_fan_adds?since=2014-07-01&until=2014-07-15
```

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/insights#page_users